# Widget area inside a widget

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

I tried putting `dynamic_sidebar('widget-id')` inside a custom widget I created and it worked. The only thing I can't figure out is how I can do this through a loop. Is there a way that when the widget is active, it registers a sidebar automatically with the same id as the `dynamic_sidebar` function inside it?

Comment: Ehm. So you are trying to implement sidebar inside a widget inside a sidebar? That's an interesting thought but is a little exotic... I am not sure there is clean way to do it though, don't think widget code fires as often as you would need it to...

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense...I am trying to create a nested widgets page so I can do a drag and drop rows and columns page..  I think maybe I will try the_widget instead.. thanks